# Drag DataGrid Column header and drop onto a label?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I want to add a "drop" area to the existing WPF DataGrid, above the column headers. In that area I want to allow the user to drop column headers that represent the columns to be grouped and to ungroup those columns by removing them from this area. I'm not able to drag the tiles and then drop onto a label. My approach consisted of Detecting drag as a combination of MouseMove and MouseLeftButtonDown but it din't work. Sample Code:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Table", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Scan Count", typeof(string));                
             DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Scan Count"] = sum.ToString();
            dr["logical reads"] = sum1.ToString();

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                ICollectionView cvTasks = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GridView1.ItemsSource);
                if (cvTasks != null && cvTasks.CanGroup == true)
                {
                    cvTasks.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
                    cvTasks.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Table"));                        
                }
            }
public class Tasks : ObservableCollection<Task>
    {
        //Creating the Tasks collection in this way enables data binding from XAML.            
    }
```

I want to remove this Button and introduce a Drag-Drop of the Column name ("Table")onto a label. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal things you should do:

1) Re-style `DataGridColumnHeader` to add `PreviewMouseMove` event handler.
2) In event handler, initiate drag/drop operation.
3) Add `GroupStyle` to `DataGrid`.
4) For the element, which is drop target, handle `Drop` event and update `GroupDescriptions`.

XAML:

```
<Grid>        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="MyGroupDescriptionsList" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop"/>

    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding Name}">
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding A}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding B}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="C" Binding="{Binding C}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code (assumes, that column header contains only strings):

```
    private void DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var header = e.OriginalSource as ContentControl;
            if (header != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(header, new DataObject(typeof(string), header.Content.ToString()), DragDropEffects.Move);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var columnName = (string)e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));

            MyGroupDescriptionsList.Items.Add(columnName);

            var sourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyDataGrid.ItemsSource);
            sourceView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(columnName));
            sourceView.Refresh();

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Un-grouping is similar.