# Datagrid DragDrop to group disables sorting

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, columnheader

I have a WPF Datagrid where I have added functionality to drag a column header to a Listbox to group based on a previous post [Drag DataGrid Column header and drop onto a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232389/drag-datagrid-column-header-and-drop-onto-a-label).  An issue I am having is when the DoDragDrop function is called, it disables the click-to-sort functionality of the Datagrid.  Is there a way to Drag-Drop column headers to group, but still be able to click to sort?

```
private void DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {               
        var header = e.OriginalSource as ContentControl;
        if (header != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(header, new DataObject(typeof(string), header.Content.ToString()), DragDropEffects.Move);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        var columnName = (string)e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));

        this.GroupedColumns.Add(columnName);

        var sourceView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataGrid.ItemsSource);
        sourceView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(columnName));
        sourceView.Refresh();

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I'm hooking into the events through XAML

```
ListBox Name="HeaderListBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedColumns}" AllowDrop="True" Margin="5" Drop="ListBox_Drop"

        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">                    
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: You should add some code to show what you have tried

Comment: Adding SortMemberPath in the column definitions might fix it, but I can't tell since you may not be explicitly defining your columns or a number of other possible issues

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  My code implements the DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove and ListBox_Drop method calls as shown in the link i have in my description.  The grouping works very well but it disables sorting when I click on the column headers.  I am not defining my columns, I am setting the DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataTable.AsDataView() and autogenerating columns.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by saving off the position on left mouse down then checking in the mouse move handler:

```
    private void DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        columnDragDropStartPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    public void DataGridHeader_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = columnDragDropStartPoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {
            var header = e.Source as DataGridColumnHeader;
            if (header != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(header, new DataObject(typeof(string[]), new[] { header.Column.SortMemberPath.ToString(), header.Content.ToString() }), DragDropEffects.Move);
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```